# How do I append a Web Component created programmatically?

Tags: web-component, appendchild, custom-element

I created a Web Component class to extend *div*, and used `customElements.define()` to define it:

```
class Resize_Div extends HTMLDivElement {
  constructor(){
      super();
      this.cpos = [0,0];
      <etc.>
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log( 'connected' );
  }
  <etc.>
}

customElements.define('resize-div', Resize_Div, { extends:'div'} );
```

If I test in html, as `<div is:'resize-div'> </div>`, it works fine.

Now I want to use createElement to create an instance programmatically, using the options to declare the ***is***, as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement#Web_component_example):

```
let dv = document.createElement('ul', { is: 'resize-div' })
```

The browser developer tools show it created, with outerHTML as below:

```
outerHTML: "<div is="resize-div"></div>"
```

As documented, "The new element [has]  an ***is*** attribute whose value is the custom element's tag name."

Now I set id, class, and style, and attach the new element to the DOM via:

```
document.getElementById( parent ).appendChild( dv );
```

Now look at it again: the ***is*** attribute is stripped off and it doesn't function as a Web Component:

```
attributes: NamedNodeMap
0: id
1: class
2: style
length: 3
```

The docs for the deprecated registerElement [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement) show an example using `document.body.appendChild( new myTag() )`, but that's obsolete.

So what is the correct way to create a Web Component programmatically and attach it to a document?

(ps. I'm working on Chromium Version 70.0.3538.67 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu, running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Answer (score 10):

You've defined an extended `<div>` but you try to create a `<ul>` element.

If you create a `<div>` instead it will work:

```
let dv = document.createElement('div', { is: 'resize-div' })
```

The `new` syntax also works:

```
document.body.appendChild( new Resize_Div )
```

NB: When you create an customized built-in element programmatically the `is` attribute is [not added in the HTML code](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-customized-builtin-example) but it still acts as a custom element, and `outerHTML` will return the HTML with `is` correctly populated [as explained in the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#attr-is-during-serialization).

Answer (score 1):

You can also create the element without this `{is: 'tag'}` object. May or may not be useful in some situations.

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    })
    shadow.append(Object.assign(
      document.createElement('h1'), {
        textContent: 'Impossibru!'
      },
    ))
  }
}

customElements.define('my-custom-element', MyElement)
const el = document.createElement('my-custom-element')
document.body.append(el)
```