# EmberJS and web components: extend an existing HTML tag within an initializer (is it possible?)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

***Edit:*** this issue only seems to be in the .hbs rendering as this code does work when the extended web component is inserted in the top level index.html of the EmberJS project

***Edit 2:*** However, when I put it in a minimal .hbs example, then it did work. So it is clearly an interaction with EmberJS rendering and perhaps with Handlebars, somehow.

***Edit 3:*** The issue also persist when I use Glimmer as a standalone rendering library and build these web components via the `constructor()` function of a Glimmer component (hacky, I know, but it works for standalone custom web components).

I am trying to understand how to use web components in EmberJS. I know that I could rewrite a web component into an EmberJS component, but that is not the point. I want to know how to directly integrate web components into EmberJS.

There is a tutorial that describes how to make custom web components and put that in EmberJS by making an initializer.

https://tenbit.co/blog/a-simple-way-to-integrate-web-components-with-your-ember-app/

So you'd think, that it is a piece of cake to do the same thing for an extended native HTML component right? It turns out that it isn't.

Here is a minimal example of what isn't working. In this particular example `<p>hello world</p>` gets displayed but `<p>hello Mars</p>` does not. However, in the standalone HTML file (see on the bottom of this post) which has the same classes and `define()` calls, then it does work.

I also made an EmberJS Twiddle, in which you can see it: https://ember-twiddle.com/5b85957f52aba288bfe9e94ce42b811e

```
// app/initializers/custom-elements.js
class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("constructor() HelloWorld");
    let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<p>hello world</p>`;
  }
}

//similar to HelloWorld -- it's simply an extension
class TestingAParagraph extends HTMLParagraphElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("constructor() TestingAParagraph");
    let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<p>hello Mars</p>`;
  }
}

export function initialize(application) {
  window.customElements.define("hello-world", HelloWorld);
  window.customElements.define("testing-a-paragraph", TestingAParagraph, {
    extends: "p"
  });
}

export default {
  initialize
};
```

Here is the Handlebars file:

```
{{!-- my-template.hbs --}}
<p>Bladiebla</p>
<hello-world></hello-world>
<p>A test is coming</p>
<p is="testing-a-paragraph"></p>
```

Note: this minimal example does work as a standalone HTML file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        // app/initializers/custom-elements.js
        class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
          constructor() {
            super();
            console.log("constructor() HelloWorld");
            let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
            shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<p>hello world</p>`;
          }
        }
    
        //similar to HelloWorld -- it's simply an extension
        class TestingAParagraph extends HTMLParagraphElement {
          constructor() {
            super();
            console.log("constructor() TestingAParagraph");
            let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
            shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<p>hello Mars</p>`;
          }
        }
    
    
        window.customElements.define("hello-world", HelloWorld);
        window.customElements.define("testing-a-paragraph", TestingAParagraph, {
          extends: "p"
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Bladiebla</p>
      <hello-world></hello-world>
      <p>A test is coming</p>
      <p is="testing-a-paragraph"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That's a good question! I'm not an expert in Glimmer VM internals but if I remember correctly it's using a `document.createElement()` and `element.setAttribute()` under the hood. Did you tried to create the `<p is="testing-a-paragraph"></p>` with that plain JavaScript functions? Does it work in that case?

Comment: Yes, it does, that's what the bottom code snippet is showing.

Answer (score 0):

In the answer, my extendable component is an `h1` as opposed to a `p`. As it made things easier to debug.

I figured out that the flow works as stated by jelhan in the comments.

1. There is a `createElement` (I'm a 100% positive as I saw in the debugger that my `h1` custom tag was breaking on `__openElement`).
2. It then parses all the attributes one by one with `setAttribute` (100% positive, because debugger). Ultimately, the "is" attribute is set by `setAttribute`. I know that when `setAttribute` is used, then the web component will not be instantiated.
3. It ends with an `insertBefore` call, at either a `flushElement` or somewhere else (I saw this in my debugger, didn't bother to pinpoint it).

There is a Stackoverflow question on how [a web component should be added in vanillaJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718081/how-do-i-append-a-web-component-created-programmatically).

With that knowledge, I created a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43pjLz6e/), in which you see the workflow of how Glimmer does it now (workflow-wise), and how Glimmer could be doing it.

**I also created a hacky workaround for statically defined elements in a .hbs file** (warning: I don't create libraries, I merely poke around in them)

You need to replace `__setAttribute` with something like this:

```
__setAttribute(name, value, namespace) {
  if(name === "is"){ //hack, hack, hackerdeehack
    //I need the actual document, this.dom doesn't cut it. I suppose it's kind of like a shadow DOM, similar to what ReactJS does.
    let webComponent = window.document.createElement(this.constructing.tagName, { is: value });
    //copy attributes that are already parsed
    [...this.constructing.attributes].forEach( attr => { this.dom.setAttribute(webComponent, attr.nodeName, attr.nodeValue, namespace) });
    this.constructing = webComponent;
  }
  this.dom.setAttribute(this.constructing, name, value, namespace);
}
```

Ultimately, it's up to the EmberJS/Glimmer maintainers to propose a certain way forward. This particular hack was made, because I did not want to mess around with the VM and I also did not want to mess around with the parsing behavior of Glimmer. But I did want to see if I was right in my thinking, and I am (2 days ago, I didn't know that Glimmer existed, so I needed to be a bit thorough).

**Some extra info for the curious people**

Terminology that I saw:

- opcodes: VM thingy, I kind of forgot what it meant in a VM context, but I've seen it in my compiler construction and computer architecture courses. I always translate it as: the table of numbers to which CPUs understand what instruction they should execute.
- System calls: DOM function calls are system calls, as they are what the rendering engine is about.

A couple of handy breakpoints (+ `console.log()`s) in order to verify the workflow that I outlined:

```
//element-builder.js
__openElement(tag) {
  console.log('NewElementBuilder - __openElement', tag, [this.element], this.element.attributes, 'modules');
  debugger;
  return this.dom.createElement(tag, this.element);
}

__setAttribute(name, value, namespace) {
  debugger;
  this.dom.setAttribute(this.constructing, name, value, namespace); //this is how the "is" attribute is set
}

//note: it could also be that __flushElement is called... I didn't check this thoroughly
__appendText(text) { 
  let { dom, element, nextSibling } = this;
  debugger;
  console.log('__appendText', dom, element, nextSibling, text);
  let node = dom.createTextNode(text);
  dom.insertBefore(element, node, nextSibling);
  return node;
}

// just to be sure
__flushElement(parent, constructing) {
  debugger;
  this.dom.insertBefore(parent, constructing, this.nextSibling); 
}
```

Comment: If `var newNode = document.createElement("div"); newNode.setAttribute('is', 'testing-a-paragraph')` is not working, Glimmer VM may need a special handling for the `is` attribute. This may not be implemented (yet). I would recommend to open a GitHub issue.

Comment: I already opened an issue for it and redirected to this SO question.

Comment: It's this issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/18508